# Error with socket.io. It does not send messages

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, socket.io

I am developing a website with React, Nodejs and mongodb.It deploy in Heroku the backend and gh-pages the fron-end.  When chatting using socket.io and socket.client I run into the following problem:

First I show a form to add your name and the room you want to create for the chat. Once the form is filled, we go to the chat, where it correctly shows me the component with the user's name and the name of the room created. The problem is that it does not show me the welcome message that I have created, nor do I receive or send new messages. What could be the problem?

**index.js**

```
const server = http.createServer(app);//creando el server con http y express como handle request
const options={
    cors:true,
    origins:["[url_de_la_web]"],
   }
const client = socketio(server,options);

const {addUser, removeUser, getUser, getUserInRoom} =require('./controllers/user');


server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Server running in"+port)
  })

  

  

client.on('connection', (socket) => {
   
    socket.on('join', ({name, room}, callback)=>{
        const {error, user}= addUser({id:socket.id, name, room});
        
        if(error) return callback (error);
        
        socket.emit('message', {user:'admin', text:`${user.name}, Bienvenido a la sala ${user.room}`});
        socket.broadcast.to(user.room).emit('message',{user:'admin', text:`${user.name}, se acaba de unir!`});

        socket.join(user.room);

        client.to(user.room).emit('roomData', {room: user.room, users: getUserInRoom(user.room)})

        callback();
    });

    socket.on('sendMessage', (message, callback)=>{
      
        const user=getUser(socket.id);
      
        client.to(user.room).emit('message', {user:user.name, text:message});
        client.to(user.room).emit('roomData', {room: user.room, users: getUserInRoom(user.room)});
        callback();
    });


    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
       const user= removeUser(socket.id);

       if(user){
           client.to(user.room).emit('message', {user:'admin', text:`${user.name} ha abandonado la sala.`})
       }
    })
    
});
```

**Chat.js**

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import queryString from 'query-string';
import InfoBar from './InfoBar';
import Input from './Input';
import Messages from './Messages';


import io from 'socket.io-client';
import './Chat.css';


let socket;

const Chat=({location}) =>{

       const [name, setName] = useState('');
       const [room, setRoom] = useState('');
       const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
       const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
       const ENDPOINT='[url_de_mongodb]'

    useEffect(()=>{
        const {name, room}=queryString.parse(location.search);
        socket=io(ENDPOINT);

        setName(name);
        setRoom(room);
        
       socket.emit('join', {name, room}, ()=>{
        
       }); 

       return () =>{
           socket.emit('disconnect'); //linea 34
           socket.off();
       }
    }, [ENDPOINT, location.search]);


    useEffect(()=>{
        socket.on('message', (message)=>{
            setMessages([...messages, message]);
        });
    },[messages]);

    // funcion para enviar mensajes

    const sendMessage =(event) =>{
    
        event.preventDefault();

        if(message){
            socket.emit('sendMessage', message, ()=> setMessage(''));
        }
    }

    console.log(message, messages);
    
        return (
            <div className="outerContainer">
               <div className="container">
                <InfoBar room={room}/>
                <Messages messages={messages} name={name}/>
                <Input message={message} setMessage={setMessage} sendMessage={sendMessage}/>
               </div>
              

            </div>

        );
   
}

export default Chat;
```

**Messages.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ScrollToBottom from 'react-scroll-to-bottom';
import Message from './Message';
import './Messages.css';

const Messages = ({messages, name})=>(

<ScrollToBottom className="messages">
    {messages.map((message, i) =><div key={i}><Message message={message} name={name} /></div> )}

</ScrollToBottom>
   
    
)

export default Messages;
```

**Message.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ScrollToBottom from 'react-scroll-to-bottom';

import './Message.css';

import ReactEmoji from 'react-emoji';

const Message = ({ message :{user, text}, name }) => {

    let isSentByCurrentUser = false;

    const trimedName = name.trim().toLowerCase();
    if (user === trimedName) {
        isSentByCurrentUser = true;
    }

    return (
        isSentByCurrentUser
            ? (
                <div className="messageContainer justifyEnd" >
                    <p className="sentText pr-10">{trimedName}</p>
                    <div className="messageBox backgroundBlue">
                        <p className="messageText colorWhite">{ReactEmoji.emojify(text)}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            )
            : (
                <div className="messageContainer justifyStart">
               
                <div className="messageBox backgroundLight">
                    <p className="messageText colorDark">{ReactEmoji.emojify(text)}</p>
                </div>
                <p className="sentText pl-10">{user}</p>
            </div>
        )
    )


}

export default Message;
```

If you need more information, tell me !! thankkkk you! :)

Comment: Shouldn't the ```const ENDPOINT='[url_de_mongodb]'``` have the sever url instead of mongo's url?

Comment: yes, ENDPOINT have the server url of mongodb.